# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) crash

Tags: ios, swift, api

So, I am having the common problem of the "NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)" error in my Swift code when attempting to access an API.  However, when I try using the common workarounds in the info.plist with NSAppTransportSecurity I get the "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)".  Below is my code, I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on here.  Any assistance here would be much appreciated.

```
func getMoviesNowPlayingData(page:Int, completion: (dict: [String:Any]) -> ()) {

    let urlString : String = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=ebea8cfca72fdff8d2624ad7bbf78e4c&page=\(page)"
    let escapedUrlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
    let apiURL = NSURL(string:escapedUrlString!)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    session.dataTaskWithURL(apiURL!, completionHandler: { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) in
        //NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802) occurs here

        do {
            if let data2 = data {
                let jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data2, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [String:Any]
                //EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) crash occurs here
                completion(dict: jsonDict)
            }
        } catch {
            //handle NSError
            print("error")
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: @Rob Thanks for pointing that out! I'm still getting the hang of casting in Swift.  The JSON is in a standard dictionary format, what is the difference between Any and AnyObject?

Comment: Unrelated, but I'm unclear why you're using mutable containers when you're casting this to a Swift dictionary that you're just passing back. I'd suggest using `[]` for the options of `JSONObjectWithData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the line that says:

```
let jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data2, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [String:Any]
```

The forced cast, `as!` is failing. I'd discourage the use of forced casts, if you can. But, as to why it fails, JSON contains class types, so you should use `AnyObject`, not `Any`, e.g.:

```
guard let jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data2, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
    print("not a dictionary")
    return
}

// use `jsonDict` here
```

In a comment above, you suggest that it failed when you tried casting it to a `NSDictionary`, too. I'd suggest you try that again, because if the JSON is a dictionary, the returned object *is* a `NSDictionary`, so that cast wouldn't fail. I suspect there was some other problem going on when you tried that.